# Can we draw Spikey?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

["Spikey" is the logo of Wolfram Research, makers of Mathematica and the Wolfram Language.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spikey.html) 
I thought it would be a fun experiment, to draw the various versions of "Spikey" in Tex. [image]

Comment: `*`⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀:-)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well, you could get the data of the `"TriakisIcosahedron"`, let Mathematica order its faces according to their distance to the observer, and draw them. Or use a patch plot that ships with `pgfplots`. So yes, it could be possible to draw something like this, but it will be large efforts.

Comment: @HenriMenke Honestly, I didnt know where to begin, what I drew using tikz, was not worthy to be shared.

Comment: From the version 6 of Mathematica the logo has been more red _"because represent all the blood, sweat and long nights that my coworkers put into Version 6 over the years"_ see  [Michael Trott post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2007/05/22/making-the-mathematica-6-spikey/)

Comment: @ vi pa that is a very useful link !

Comment: The Spikey version 1 is very easy to do with [Sketch](http://sketch4latex.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just for fun. One can indeed draw something going in that direction. If you want to run this, download the `tikz-3dtools` library from [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex), and put it somewhere where TeX can find it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{closed polygon/.style={insert path={foreach \Coord [count=\nCoord] in {#1}
 {\ifnum\nCoord=1
  \Coord
 \else
  -- \Coord
 \fi} -- cycle}},polygon/.style={insert path={foreach \Coord [count=\nCoord] in {#1}
 {\ifnum\nCoord=1
  \Coord
 \else
  -- \Coord
 \fi}}}}
\makeatletter


% main code
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\tdplotsetmaincoords{90+30*sin(\X)}{\X}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,font=\sffamily,fill opacity=1,line
join=round,scale=pi]
  \path[tdplot_screen_coords,use as bounding box] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  % define the vertices (there are certainly superior naming conventions)
  \path   (0., 0., 1.63925) coordinate (p1)  
 (0.262866, -0.809017, 1.11352) coordinate (p2)  
 (0.262866, 0.809017, 1.11352) coordinate (p3)  
 (0.850651, 0., 1.11352) coordinate (p4)  
 (0., 0., -1.63925) coordinate (p5)   
 (-0.262866, -0.809017, -1.11352) coordinate (p6)  
 (-0.262866, 0.809017, -1.11352) coordinate (p7) 
 (0.688191, -0.5, -1.11352) coordinate (p8)  
 (0.688191, 0.5, -1.11352) coordinate (p9)  
 (-0.850651, 0., -1.11352) coordinate (p10)  
 (-0.688191, -0.5, 1.11352) coordinate (p11)  
 (-0.688191, 0.5, 1.11352) coordinate (p12)  
 (-1.37638, 0., -0.262866) coordinate (p13)  
 (1.11352, -0.809017, -0.262866) coordinate (p14)  
 (1.11352, 0.809017, -0.262866) coordinate (p15) 
 (-0.425325, -1.30902, -0.262866) coordinate (p16)  
 (-0.425325, 1.30902, -0.262866) coordinate (p17) 
 (1.37638, 0., 0.262866) coordinate (p18)  
 (0.425325, -1.30902, 0.262866) coordinate (p19) 
 (0.425325, 1.30902, 0.262866) coordinate (p20)  
 (-1.11352, -0.809017, 0.262866) coordinate (p21)  
 (-1.11352, 0.809017, 0.262866) coordinate (p22) 
 (1.18617, -0.861803, 0.733094) coordinate (p23) 
 (1.18617, 0.861803, 0.733094) coordinate (p24)  
 (-1.46619, 0., 0.733094) coordinate (p25)  
 (-0.453077, -1.39443, 0.733094) coordinate (p26) 
 (-0.453077, 1.39443, 0.733094) coordinate (p27) 
 (1.46619, 0., -0.733094) coordinate (p28)  
 (-1.18617, -0.861803, -0.733094) coordinate (p29)  
 (-1.18617, 0.861803, -0.733094) coordinate (p30) 
 (0.453077, -1.39443, -0.733094) coordinate (p31) 
 (0.453077, 1.39443, -0.733094) coordinate (p32); 
  % define the plane data as a list of <drawing options>/<shape>/<vertices> 
  \def\PlaneData{%
  {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p1),(p26),(p2)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p5),(p31),(p6)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p3),(p27),(p1)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p7),(p32),(p5)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p19),(p26),(p31)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p32),(p27),(p20)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p26),(p23),(p2)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p3),(p24),(p27)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p30),(p29),(p13)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p29),(p26),(p21)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p22),(p27),(p30)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p16),(p26),(p29)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p30),(p27),(p17)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p31),(p29),(p6)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p7),(p30),(p32)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p31),(p23),(p19)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p20),(p24),(p32)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p18),(p24),(p23)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p8),(p28),(p31)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p9),(p32),(p28)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p14),(p23),(p31)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p32),(p24),(p15)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p23),(p24),(p4)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p31),(p28),(p14)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p28),(p32),(p15)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p21),(p25),(p29)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p30),(p25),(p22)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p28),(p23),(p14)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p15),(p24),(p28)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p18),(p23),(p28)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p28),(p24),(p18)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p29),(p25),(p13)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p13),(p25),(p30)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p2),(p23),(p1)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p8),(p31),(p5)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p1),(p24),(p3)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p5),(p32),(p9)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p19),(p23),(p26)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p27),(p24),(p20)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p11),(p26),(p1)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p6),(p29),(p5)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p1),(p27),(p12)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p5),(p30),(p7)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p1),(p25),(p11)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p5),(p29),(p10)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p12),(p25),(p1)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p10),(p30),(p5)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p1),(p23),(p4)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p5),(p28),(p8)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p4),(p24),(p1)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p9),(p28),(p5)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p10),(p29),(p30)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p21),(p26),(p25)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p22),(p25),(p27)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p16),(p29),(p31)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p32),(p30),(p17)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p25),(p26),(p11)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p27),(p25),(p12)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p31),(p26),(p16)},% 
 {draw,fill=randomcolor}/closed polygon/{(p17),(p27),(p32)}}
  % normal of screen (last row of the rotation matrix)
  \path[overlay] ({sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*sin(\tdplotmainphi)},
       {-1*sin(\tdplotmaintheta)*cos(\tdplotmainphi)},
       {cos(\tdplotmaintheta)}) coordinate (n); 
  % build up the list of projections  
  \foreach \Style/\Poly/\CoordLst [count=\nC] in \PlaneData
  {%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybarycenter}{barycenter("\CoordLst")}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\currproj}{TD("(n)o(\mybarycenter)")}
   \foreach \Coord [count=\nP] in \CoordLst
   {\expandafter\xdef\csname td@vertex@\romannumeral\nP\endcsname{\Coord}}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mynormal}{TD("\td@vertex@i-\td@vertex@ii x\td@vertex@iii-\td@vertex@ii")}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mysign}{ifthenelse(TD("(\mynormal)o(0,0,1)")<0,-1,1)}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mylightproj}{60+\mysign*40*TD("(\mynormal)o(0.3,0.1,1)")}
   %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mylightproj}{20+\nC}
   \expandafter\xdef\csname tikz@td@saturation\romannumeral\nC\endcsname{\mylightproj}
   \ifnum\nC=1
    \xdef\LstProj{\currproj}
  \else
    \xdef\LstProj{\LstProj,\currproj}
  \fi
  \expandafter\gdef\csname tikz@td@layer\romannumeral\nC\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname tikz@td@poly\romannumeral\nC\endcsname{%
  \noexpand\path[\Style,\Poly={\CoordLst}];}
  \xdef\tikz@td@planes{\nC}%
  }
 \foreach \X [count=\nC] in \LstProj
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mypos}{pos(\X,"\LstProj")}
  \expandafter\edef\expandafter\tempa{\csname tikz@td@layer\romannumeral\mypos\endcsname}%
  \edef\tempb{}%
  \ifx\tempb\tempa\relax
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikz@td@layer\romannumeral\mypos\endcsname{\nC}%
  \else 
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikz@td@layer\romannumeral\mypos\endcsname{\tempa,\nC}%
  \fi
 }
 \foreach \X in {1,...,\tikz@td@planes}
 {\expandafter\edef\expandafter\tempa{\csname tikz@td@layer\romannumeral\X\endcsname}%
  \edef\tempb{}%
  \ifx\tempb\tempa\relax
  \else 
    \foreach \Y in \tempa
    {
      \edef\mysaturation{\csname tikz@td@saturation\romannumeral\Y\endcsname}
      \colorlet{randomcolor}{red!\mysaturation}
      \csname tikz@td@poly\romannumeral\Y\endcsname
    }
  \fi}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother  
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is nowhere near as fancy as Mathematica's version. Absolutely. It was just an exercise for me to see how well some 3d ordering routine works. As of now I think it does.